# Calculations based on series of previous rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to `SQL` (only have done a course online so I am familiar with basics). I think the best way to describe my problem is by showing it through the table shown below:

[image: table]

I am trying to calculate the entries in `col1`. 
What should I do?

THE CODE I AM USING IS:
SELECT *,SUM((col2)*POWER(1-col3,[ROW]-1)) OVER (ORDER BY [ROW] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) FROM [bak].[table]

BUT WHAT THIS DOES FOR EXAMPLE TO 4 IS: (1-C)^2*B1+(1-C)^2*B2+(1-C)^2*B3 INSTEAD OF (1-C)^2*B1+(1-C)*B2+B3

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Can you please add some pieces of information about what you tried so far?

Comment: You would need to make use of recursive cte to get this done. since the formula being used is dependent on the previous row

Comment: col3 seems to have a constant value. why need a column for that?

Comment: what is the 5th row formula going to be

Comment: If you need to add additional information to your question then you should [edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21789/204922) your original question.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . You need to raise values to a certain power, based on how far back they go.  Then you have a `sum()`.

You can do this by assigning a sequential number and doing the cumulative sum with `power()`.  But then you divide out the current row.

Without sample data, it is tricky to be sure this is exactly right, but the idea is:

```
select t.*,
       (sum(b * power(1 - c, seqnum)) over (order by id rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) /
        power(1 - c, seqnum + 1)
       )
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by id desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```